# using foreach loop how to read specific property in "stdClass"?

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

I have an array full of stdClass objects. I just need to unserialize a specific property in one of the objects in each index. This is what i'm trying but the object is still serialized so perhaps im just referecing it wrong. How should I be reading the 'exampleData' property?

```
foreach ($rowset as $value) {
    $value = unserialize($value -> exampleData);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($rowset as &$value) {
    $value = unserialize($value -> exampleData);
}
```

You need to pass-by-reference